# Get binary object from Salesforce with Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce-lightning

I'm able to send request and get answers from Salesforce using client id + client secret and use the auth token.
Now I need to get "pdf" files stored in SalesForce Lightning using this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                string restQuery = $"{ServiceUrl}{queryObject}";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                response = client.GetAsync(restQuery).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = null;
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                    mybytearray = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
                }
```

Without the token I get "401 not authorised", with this code I get "bad request".

I tried without the token, with, also perform a request.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                queryRecordReturn = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Damn, seems that no one can help me :(